# stop music on incoming call and when im calling someone

Tags: android, android-activity

Hi i would like to stop music totally when someone call me and if i call someone right now it just like the app put the volume down on call and i still can listen in background very low but its there i would like to stop music heres my current code:

```
PhoneStateListener phoneStateListener = new PhoneStateListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
        if (state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING) {
            wasPlayingBeforePhoneCall = radioService.isPlaying();
            radioService.stop();
        } else if (state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE) {
            if (wasPlayingBeforePhoneCall) {
                radioService.play();
            }
        } else if (state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK) {
            // A call is dialing, active or on hold
            wasPlayingBeforePhoneCall = radioService.isPlaying();
            radioService.stop();
        }
        super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);
    }
};
```

play method:

```
public void play() {
    if (hasConnectivity()) {
        if (getCurrentStationType().equals(TYPE_AAC)) {
            prepare();
        } else {
            if (isPrepared) {
                isRadioPlaying = true;
                mediaPlayer.start();
                System.out.println("RadioService: play");
                setStatus(STATUS_PLAYING);
                sendBroadcast(new Intent(MODE_PLAYING));
            } else {
                prepare();
            }
        }
    } else
        sendBroadcast(new Intent(MODE_STOPPED));

}
```

stop method:

```
public void stop() {
    timeCounter = -1;
    resetMetadata();
    isPrepared = false;
    System.out.println("RadioService: stop");

    if (getCurrentStationType().equals(TYPE_AAC)) {
        if (isRadioPlaying) {
            isRadioPlaying = false;
            multiPlayer.stop();
        }
        // else
        // sendBroadcast(new Intent(MODE_STOPPED));
    } else {
        mediaPlayer.stop();
        mediaPlayer.reset();

        isRadioPlaying = false;
        setStatus(STATUS_STOPPED);
        sendBroadcast(new Intent(MODE_STOPPED));
    }
    // clearNotification();
}
```

im doing something wrong?

thank you.

Comment: Can you post your radioService.play() and radioService.stop() methods?

Comment: i just updated my code

Comment: Don't use PhoneStateListener, use AudioManager: http://developer.android.com/training/managing-audio/audio-focus.html this is exactly what it's built for

Comment: any example on implementing it in my code?